# Evaluating Elisp expression inside JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, elisp, expression, evaluation

I try to evaluate simple exression `(/ 72 24)` using `C-x C-e` when it's inserted inside javascript code (in javascript mode), but it throw an error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax "] in a list")
  read(#<buffer SomeFile.js>)
  preceding-sexp()
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

It work when I insert it into empty buffer. Why `eval-last-sexp` don't work in this way?

Comment: Writing Elisp code in a javascript-mode buffer is a bad idea.

Comment: @Stefan I just wanted to calcuate `(/ 72 24)` and I was in javascript-mode buffer and it didn't work so I just ask why.

Comment: In such situations, the best option is to use `M-:` (of course, you can also use another buffer like `*scratch*` or `*IELM*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the point exactly after the closing parenthesis.
Then it should work.

### UPD The / messes up the syntax

I've checked again and the fault is the js-mode redefining the
syntax table for its regex literal.

Here's the fix:

```
(defun eval-last-sexp-js (eval-last-sexp-arg-internal)
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (while (re-search-backward "(/" (line-beginning-position) t)
      (remove-text-properties 
       (match-beginning 0)
       (1+ (match-end 0))
       '(syntax-table))))
  (eval-last-sexp eval-last-sexp-arg-internal))
```

`eval-last-sexp-js` will work the same as `eval-last-sexp`.
You can rebind it specifically for `js-mode` if you want.